# Work experience documents for New Zealand - Skilled Migrant

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, new-zealand

This is regarding the *resident visa* application under *skilled migrant category*.

With regards to *work experience* documents, The check-list expects below information:

### [image]

Am I suppose to submit,

```
1) Joining letter
2) Relieving letter
3) Appraisal letter
4) Payslips(3-6)
5) Form-16
```

as originals or attested copies?
It is not feasible for me to send original documents as I need them for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The required documents table indicates that you must present letters of reference from all employers you have during the last 10 years. Those **reference letters must be originals**, and may require that you contact a previous employer and request one, written on company letterhead, and signed.  You would want to keep a copy for yourself.

For the next group (joining, relieving, appraisal letters, and 3-6 months of most recent payslips), take both an original and a copy of each and **have them attested**. If any are multiple pages, each page should be attested separately.

The form is meant to be printed by you, completed, signed and the **original** accompanies your application. Again, you should keep a copy for yourself.